# Remove Squiggly Lines from HTML

Tags: html, vim

I was wondering how I could remove the ~ signs from my HTML file. Right now at the end of my file, there are a bunch of ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ and for some reason I cannot delete them and they are displaying in my HTML page. Any one else have this problem before? This is how the code looks like at the end:

```
  </script>                                                                    
  </head>                                                 
  </html>                                                                      
~                                                                            
~                                                      
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                            
~                                                                            
~                                                       
~                                                                            
~                                                                            
~                                                       
~                                                                            
~                                                                               
~                                                                            
~
```

Thanks!

Comment: please show the code..

Comment: Code is added. Don't know how much of a help it would be though.

Comment: How are you trying to delete them and what happens when you do?

Comment: Open file. Place cursor at the last tilde. Press delete repeatedly until all tildes are gone. Save file.

If that doesn't work, the tildes are being added by something server side.

Comment: `"for some reason I cannot delete them"` - How are you *trying* to delete them?  If you're unable to modify and save the HTML file then I doubt that has much to do with the tilde characters.

Comment: I am using Vim and pressing dd to try to delete the lines. It seem as though the lines are invincible or something because they just dont disappear!!! I will try deleting them with a text editor instead.

Comment: Are the tildes actually in the HTML file, or are you only seeing this when you're in Vim?

Comment: The original HTML file does not have them and when I am on gedit, for example, I do not see them. But when I am in Vi, which is the only text editing program I can use to code the actual document, the squiggly lines appear and are being displayed on the site.

Comment: Never mind I fixed it. Maybe the squiggly lines were somehow added into the HTML file...who knows. Vim still shows the lines but when I run the page it doesn't so it's fixed. One of the weird problems I've faced. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These ~ are added by your tool to tell you that these lines are past the end of file. They are not part of the file. Thats why you cannot delete them.

Comment: That makes sense, but I'd think that the page would not display these lines when you actually run it.

Comment: They are displayed in your browser?!

Comment: Never mind I fixed it. They WERE displayed in my browser, yes. Maybe the squiggly lines were somehow added into the HTML file...who knows. Vim still shows the lines but when I run the page it doesn't so it's fixed. One of the weird problems I've faced. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

These *tilde* characters appearing after last line of your code until the bottom of Vim window are, of course, Vim-specific thing. Lines starting with ~ in Vim are visual aid by which you can tell you’re not looking at empty lines of code, but rather that you’re past the end of file already and there’s no content here. In Vim,

> “tilde” lines mean space for growth past the present 
>   end-of-file.

See also:

- [I'd like to get rid of the "~" character that signals lines beyond file end](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Tilde-character-I-d-like-to-get-rid-of-the-quot-quot-character-that-signals-lines-beyond-file-end-td1191192.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help!!